# Mongo Filter Query Nested with mulitple and

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, morphia

Following is my query does exactly match with my document but still not getting output.Don't know why. Following is the document as well.

```
db.getCollection("analytics").find(
    { 
        "$and" : [
            { 
                "archive" : false
            }, 
            { 
                "platform" : "WEB"
            }, 
            { 
                "vendorId" : "3c7adbfe-14d7-4b26-9134-7e05d56573cc"
            }, 
            { 
                "createdAt" : { 
                    "$gte" : 1578268800000.0
                }
            }, 
            { 
                "createdAt" : { 
                    "$lte" : 1580860800000.0
                }
            }, 
            { 
                "$and" : [
                    { 
                        "data.mobile" : "123"
                    }, 
                    { 
                        "page" : "Loan Application"
                    }, 
                    { 
                        "event" : "click"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            { 
                "$and" : [
                    { 
                        "data.aadharNumber" : "123"
                    }, 
                    { 
                        "page" : "Personal Information"
                    }, 
                    { 
                        "event" : "click"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            { 
                "$and" : [
                    { 
                        "data.totalExp" : "5"
                    }, 
                    { 
                        "page" : "Professional Information"
                    }, 
                    { 
                        "event" : "click"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

**Documents :**

```
[
  {
    "page": "Loan Application",
    "event": "click",
    "loggedIn": true,
    "vendorId": "3c7adbfe-14d7-4b26-9134-7e05d56573cc",
    "data": {
      "first": "Praveen",
      "mobile": "1234"
    },
    "platform": "WEB"
  },
  {
    "page": "Personal Information",
    "event": "click",
    "loggedIn": true,
    "vendorId": "3c7adbfe-14d7-4b26-9134-7e05d56573cc",
    "data": {
      "panNumber": "123",
      "aadharNumber": "123"
    },
    "platform": "WEB"
  },
  {
    "page": "Professional Information",
    "event": "click",
    "loggedIn": true,
    "vendorId": "3c7adbfe-14d7-4b26-9134-7e05d56573cc",
    "data": {
      "totalExp": "5"
    },
    "platform": "WEB"
  }
]
```

Comment: are those sample docs or exact docs ? Your query needs to corrected but before even if query works but it wouldn't get any docs cause you've few fields like `archive` or `createdAt` in query doesn't exists in docs..

Comment: ignore thos field, i given only important field in order to compare.

Comment: Just don't put code. Try to explain what you want in the end ( end result).

Comment: question is document is exactly match with query, still getting nothing on querying,

Comment: You query fails on first match (archive: false). Because there is no archive key in your document

Comment: please ingnor these fields please, needs to compare with inner ands condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of issues going on with your query, you can try below query to return all documents :

```
db.getCollection("analytics").find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      {
        $eq: [
          "$platform",
          "WEB"
        ]
      },
      {
        $eq: [
          "$vendorId",
          "3c7adbfe-14d7-4b26-9134-7e05d56573cc"
        ]
      },
      {
        $or: [
          {
            "$and": [
              {
                "data": {
                  "mobile": "123"
                }
              },
              {
                "page": "Loan Application"
              },
              {
                "event": "click"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "$and": [
              {
                "data": {
                  "aadharNumber": "123"
                }
              },
              {
                "page": "Personal Information"
              },
              {
                "event": "click"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "$and": [
              {
                "data": {
                  "totalExp": "5"
                }
              },
              {
                "page": "Professional Information"
              },
              {
                "event": "click"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0Y_HviVmrcx)